# Inserting Google Analytics Content Experiments using the Node.JS Client Library

Tags: node.js, google-analytics-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to configure a content experiment using the Node.js Client Library, and have not been able to work out the syntax. Where do I put the body (an Experiment resource) as described here?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtExperimentsGuide#insert

This code, for listing existing experiments, works as expected:

```
var listExperiments = function(){
  googleapis
  .discover('analytics', 'v3')
  .execute(function(err, client) {
    var request = client
    .analytics.management.experiments.list({
        accountId : accountId,
        webPropertyId : webPropertyId,
        profileId : profileId
        })
    .withApiKey(browserAPIKey)
    .withAuthClient(oauth2Client)

      request.execute(function(err,result){
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
          res.send(402);          
        } else {
          console.log(result);
          res.send(200);
        }
      });
  });
}
```

However, when I try to insert a new experiment thusly, I receive a "Field resource is required" error.

```
var body = {       
  "name": "myExperimentName",
  "status": "READY_TO_RUN",
  "objectiveMetric":"ga:bounces",
  "variations": [
    { "name": "text1", "url":"http://www.asite.net", "status":"ACTIVE" },
    { "name": "text2", "url":"http://www.asite.net", "status":"ACTIVE" }
   ]
 };

var insertExperiment = function(){
  googleapis
  .discover('analytics', 'v3')
  .execute(function(err, client) {
    var request = client
    .analytics.management.experiments.insert({
        accountId : accountId,
        webPropertyId : webPropertyId,
        profileId : profileId,
        resource : body
        })
    .withApiKey(browserAPIKey)
    .withAuthClient(oauth2Client)

    request.execute(function(err,result){
      if (err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send(402);          
      } else {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(200);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I've tried a few configurations. Management API writes are in limited beta, but I have beta access, so that's not the problem. I've tried inserting the new experiment information directly into the insert() object, calling the experiment info object "body : body " instead of "resource : body", JSON.stringifying the body, and a few other configurations. No luck.

Any help would be great!

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387407/insert-experiment-to-google-analytics-api-gapi), but it uses the Javascript Client Library and makes RESTful requests, whereas I'd like to use the Node Library.

EDIT: Thanks to Burcu Dogan at Google. Here's the correct syntax:

```
.analytics.management.experiments.insert({
accountId : accountId,
webPropertyId : webPropertyId,
profileId : profileId
}, body)
```